# How do I create a button in Sketch (PDF) that launches a mailto link when its clicked?

Tags: pdf, sketch-app

I'm building what will be a PDF in Sketch 3.

I want to create a button (a rectangle box with "sign up" inside) that launches a mailto link when the person reading it clicks on it.

I can't figure out how to 1) add links in Sketch, or 2) make the entire button (including the border of the rectangle box) clickable, vs just the text portion.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't make hyperlinks in Sketch due to it is drawing app. But you can insert links in generated pdf, here is some advices: http://www.ehow.com/how_4707191_hyperlink-pdf-file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating PDF without links, open it in Adobe Acrobat and choose the place where you want to link like in the image below:

[image]

Then choose Create Link in the menu and select the option "Open a Web Page":
[image]

Click Next and you will be prompted with a text box. Fill it with "mailto:person@address.com" without quotation marks. And you'll be done!

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

You can actually create a hyperlink in Sketch without using Acrobat.

[Here is how it works in GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/uTZ5XNlsMTyM2hNdZd/giphy.gif)

1. Paste the link from the browser.
2. Right click on text **AND** Select the text -> **Make link**.
3. Select the text and replace it with whatever you want.

Simply clicking the text block will not reveal **Make Link** option on Right Click. 
Also selecting part of the text will not reveal this option. It has to be a **valid** link.

e.g.

- https://www.stackexchange.com -> is valid.
- stackexchange.com -> is valid.
- stackexchangecom -> is not.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on the Sketch Talk forum.  Just confirmed that it works, even with mailto: links.

"Easiest way (which is how I did it in Illustrator too) is to paste the URL you want over the text you want to hyperlink, change the URL color to the same as the background, and send it to the back underneath the original text you wanted to link. Once you export, there will be an invisible hyperlink underneath the text!"

Comment: This didn't actually work for me... BUT good to know that hyperlinks (even stripped of protocol, e.g. alesh.com, will work in PDF's exported from Sketch!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is for this problem is here

https://youtu.be/WLggIppVE1w

Comment: can you perhaps [edit] your answer and write the explanation? We don't like relying on links for full answers, it should be just extra reference. Check [answer] for more info on how the site works.